# configuring app.yaml handler for static image files

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, bootstrap-4, yaml

I have been trying to configure my app.yaml in the Google Cloud Platform.

I would like to achieve two things:

1. redirect all URLs (except images) to the main index.html in the root folder.  For example, example.com/abcd should be redirected to example.com.
2. load any image requests from the folder named "mypics".

Here is my existing app.yaml file.

```
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: true

    handlers:
    # image files
    - url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
      static_files: mypics/\1
      upload: mypics/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))

    # URL redirect
    - url: /(.*)
      static_files: index.html
      upload: index.html
```

I have managed to get the redirects working.  However, the images are not being loaded.  I have reversed the order of the handlers, which does not seem to make a difference.

If I try to load the image directly, I get the following error:

Error: Not Found
The requested URL /mypics/Diamond.png was not found on this server.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it has to do with how you specify the path to your images in your template files (i.e. html files). Let me explain with the result of the test I did on my machine

**Previously**,

Folder structure

- Project Root

  - static

    - images

      - image_1.png
      - image_2.png
  - css

app.yaml

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

Code in `index.html` file was `< img src="/static/images/image_1.png" alt="Image 1" >`.

The above worked (i.e. images were properly displayed)

Then I changed to your code

```
 - url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: mypics/\1
  upload: mypics/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
```

The images were no longer displayed. I also tried

```
- url: /static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: mypics/\1
  upload: mypics/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
```

but the images were still not displayed.

I then went back and modified the routing in `app.yaml` to

```
- url: /static/images/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: mypics/\1
  upload: mypics/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
```

The change here is that I specified the full path I used in my `index.html` i.e. `static/images/` and the images got displayed again

Comment: Now that I see it...it looks so simple.  I was not referencing the correct folder in the first line of the handler.  Thanks for solving the issue.

Comment: Cool. One more thing: If your App is going to be deployed to Google App Engine, then you should take a look at Python 3. GAE Python3 now supports most of the same bundled libraries that were available in Python27. One major exception is ```Search API``` which is not available.